# How do I get my iPhone's entire text history, accessible from my computer?

Tags: messages, data-recovery, text, data

I did this successfully some time ago by (i believe) finding the place where they were all stored in my iPhone backups and using an application to read the files. They were all there, in one place -- a history of several years that I had deleted. I would like to know how to do this again -- without using iTunes backups.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that using an iTunes backup is the only way to do this short of jailbreaking the phone (and then manually grabbing the same files that you would get out of the backup directly from the phone.)

Comment: Do you use iCloud? because they should be there already.